# Total number of $n$-cycle

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a certain theorem or axiom, which states the following:

> (*)  Let $n$ be an odd number. The number of way to write the $n$-cycle $(1,2,\dots,n)$ in the form  $uvu^{-1}v^{-1}$, is equal to $2n\cdot n!/(n+1)$.

What is $n$-cycle? When I have tried to search in Google, it said that it is nitrogen cycles, which is defined like this:

> The nitrogen cycle is the process by which nitrogen is converted between its various chemical forms.

Is it so? And what kind of application it has in numbers and permutations?

Comment: The n-cycle that google brought up is completely different to the type you are interested in.

Comment: Your search result is about chemistry, not mathematics.  Instead, try http://lmgtfy.com/?q=n-cycle+permutation&l=1

Comment: The n-cycle looks like it's simply the permutation that 'cycles' the numbers like so: $$1\to2\to3\to\cdots n\to1.$$ The counting formula sounds like interesting in and of itself, though, so I'd like to know where you read it.

Comment: I've seen [$k$-cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28mathematics%29), sure...

Answer (score 3):

An $n$-cycle in this context is a particular [cyclic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) of length $n$ of $n$ elements, compare the comments to your post.

But note that the formula in your OP cannot be correct, because for $n+1$ an odd prime it does not give an integer.